# Proof of statement regarding products and limits of sequences

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider two positive sequences $\{a_n\}_n$ and $\{b_n\}_n$. Prove that $$\liminf(a_n)\liminf(b_n) \le \liminf(a_nb_n) \le \liminf(a_n)\limsup(b_n)$$

If $\lim(a_n)=0$ it would be easy, but for the case of $\lim(a_n)>0$ I really have no idea.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not attach photos.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{k\geqslant n}a_k$ - this limit exists since the sequence $\inf_{k\geqslant n}a_k$ is monotone increasing. For any fixed $n$, we have
$$
\inf_{k\geqslant n}a_k\inf_{k\geqslant n}b_k=\inf_{k,j\geqslant n}a_kb_j \leqslant \inf_{k\geqslant n} a_kb_k,\tag 1
$$
since the sequences are positive and $$\{a_kb_j:k,j\geqslant n\}\supset\{a_kb_k:k\geqslant n\}. $$ Taking the limit of $(1)$ as $n\to\infty$ yields the first inequality.

The second inequality follows from a similar argument applied to the inequality

$$
\inf_{k\geqslant n}a_kb_k\leqslant \inf_{k\geqslant n}a_k\sup_{j\geqslant n}b_j.
$$